# How to Hide "Private" Show Pages from Other Users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In other words if a user types in for example:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/goals/3
```

they will be able to see that user's goal even if the user submitted it as "private". This is something I had overlooked because as it stands submitting via "private" hides the goal from the user's profile and the feed, but not if another user directly searches for it via the url.

How can we fix this?

**goals_controller**

```
class GoalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_goal, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :like, :user_goals]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @goals = Goal.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    elsif params[:user_id]
      @accomplished_goals = User.find(params[:user_id]).goals.accomplished.order("deadline")
      @unaccomplished_goals = User.find(params[:user_id]).goals.unaccomplished.order("deadline")
    else
      @accomplished_goals = current_user.goals.accomplished.order("deadline")
      @unaccomplished_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished.order("deadline")
    end
  end

  def user_goals
      @goals = Goal.find_by({user_id: params[:user_id]})
      render :index # or some other view
  end

  def show
    @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @goal
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
    @notable = @goal
    @notes = @notable.notes
    @note = Note.new
    @correct_user = current_user.goals.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @goal = current_user.goals.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @goal = current_user.goals.build(goal_params)
    if (params[:commit] == 'conceal')
      @goal.conceal = true
      @goal.save
      redirect_to @goal, notice: 'Goal was successfully created'
    elsif
      @goal.save
      track_activity @goal
      redirect_to @goal, notice: 'Goal was successfully created'
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Required Field: "Enter Goal"'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @goal.update(goal_params)
      redirect_to goals_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @goal.destroy
    redirect_to goals_url
  end

  def like
    @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
    @goal_like = current_user.goal_likes.build(goal: @goal)
    if @goal_like.save
      @goal.increment!(:likes)
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
    end  
      redirect_to(:back)
  end

  private
    def set_goal
      @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @goal = current_user.goals.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Not authorized to edit this goal" if @goal.nil?
    end

    def goal_params
      params.require(:goal).permit(:name, :like, :deadline, :accomplished, :tag_list, :comment, :private_submit)
    end
end
```

goal.rb

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :publish, ->{ where(:conceal => false) }
    belongs_to :user
    scope :accomplished, -> { where(accomplished: true) }
    scope :unaccomplished, -> { where(accomplished: false) }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is *private_submit* a boolean field?

If so, here's a quick way to make the show page private if the private_submit field has a value of "true".

```
class GoalsController < ApplicationController

 # Remove :edit, :update, destroy, and :user_gmails from below as the action is duplicated
 before_action :set_goal, only: [:show, :like]

  def show
    ## Remove:  @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
  end

  def like
    # Remove this as it's being called ready in set_goal: 
    # @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
    ...
  end

  ...

  def set_goal
    @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(:back) unless @goal.user_id == current_user.id or @goal.private_submit == false
  end

end
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be more efficient. Thank you Andrew for also helping me remove some unnecessary lines :]

Answer (score 6):

Please consider one of the rails authorization gems. The simplest one in my humble opinion is [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit). In the case of using pundit, you will need to make these steps:

```
# Goals controller
def set_goal
  @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
  authorize @goal
end

# GoalPolicy
def show?
  (goal.private? and goal.user == current_user) or not goal.private?
end
```

[Full list of popular ruby authorization gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization)