# RoR: delete your own comments, but not other peoples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, erb

I have a project that is running beautifully. My only problem is, you can delete anyone's comments as long as you are signed in. I need it to where you can delete your own comments, but nobody else's. Any suggestions?

in my _comment.html.erb partial:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.post, comment],
 method: :delete,
 class: "button",
 data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }%>
</p>
```

My Comment Controller:

```
def destroy
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
@comment.destroy unless comment.user != current_user

redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233690/how-to-hide-private-show-pages-from-other-users

Comment: doesn't seem like it. I'm asking how to delete your own comments, but not others. I have it to delete every comment as long as you're signed in. That is asking how to keep something private if someone searches it in the URI

Comment: The solution is the same, basically. Approaches, however, vary.

Comment: You did write an algorithm that destroys the given comment, what's wrong with just wrapping it in an `if`? What part exactly do you not know about that?

Comment: my question is edited

Answer (score 1):

You have authentification but you don't have authorization. I would suggest putting some time in investigating the authorization gems at ruby toolbox: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization.

If you don't want to go that route you could simply implement something with the following logic

```
comment.destroy unless comment.user != current_user
```

Assuming Comment belongs_to User and User has a current_user method :)

Cheers!

Comment: Didn't quite do the trick, but my question is edited with your answer in there

Comment: @BrendonBaughn are you sure you didn't make a typo ? comment.destroy unless comment.use != current_user

seems like it should be comment.user not comment.use

Comment: oh, sorry about that. I was hand writing it here because the actual code is on my laptop, and I'm using my desktop

Answer (score 0):

There is a little authorization trick that is viable when authorization errors should never happen.

**This trick equalizes authorization errors to non-existence errors.** If *a user is not authorized* to do something with a comment, the action is treated *as if that comment does not exist*. Now that you know the implications...

#### ...lo and behold, here it comes:

```
@comment = @post.comments.where(user_id: current_user.id).find(params[:id])
```